# Button stopped working when I added it to a different view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton

Working in the xib file, I moved my button from the root view to a subview (a Table View). However, when I did this, the button stopped working. It appears perfectly, but it does not respond to click (i.e. when it is clicked, it does not show the highlighted view and it does not call the IBAction set for it). How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you add your button ? Can you post some code here ?

Comment: Where have you put the button in the tableView? In a cell (prototype or static), header, footer, section header?

Comment: @Thilina - button was working in original view. I moved it to the subview via the sidebar in the Interface Builder: http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/8879/sidebaruw.png

Comment: @rickerbh it is a prototype cell.